# C# And Access 2007: Insert & Update functions not working properly?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have two functions. Insert functions provided by [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul) (thanks),......

Table Name Students

Database

```
     `Field Name    Data Type
     *StudentID Number
      StudentName   Text
      StudentCNIC   Text
      StudentDOB    Date/Time
```

*PK

```
using System.Data.OleDb; 

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=|DataDirectory|\Access_and_CSharp.accdb");
        this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.access_and_CSharpDataSet.Students);
    }
```

Insert Function

```
private void Insertbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students(StudentID, StudentName, StudentCNIC, StudentDOB) Values(@StudIDTxt, @StudNameTxt, @StudCNCITxt, @StudDOBTxt)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudIDTxt", StudIDTxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudNameTxt", StudNameTxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudCNCITxt", StudCNCITxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudDOBTxt", StudDOBTxt.Text);
        cmd.Connection=myCon;   
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         myCon.Close();
    }
```

And this is the update function

```
private void Updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Students] set [StudentName] = ?, [StudentCNIC] = ?, [StudentDOB] = ? WHERE [StudentID] = ?";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudIDTxt", StudIDTxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudNameTxt", StudNameTxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudCNCITxt", StudCNCITxt.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudDOBTxt", StudDOBTxt.Text);
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
    }
```

Problem 1 - 
When I use the insert function I can see new data at the front end. But I cannot see the new data in Access. Other times when I close the application and restart, new recorded is not there. If I look in Access application and closed it then open VS2010 application new data is not there. What is going on?

Problem 2 - 
When I use the update function, data remains updated while the application running first time. This is not true when the application is closed and running again. Where have I gone wrong?

For both of problems can anyone see where the problem(s) is/are?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
Updating to say I am looking the following website where I have gone wrong. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/e628d9/inserting-retrieving-records-from-ms-access-2007-using-odbc/

**Update**
I have Windows 7, MS Access 2007 and VS 2010. I am wondering if this is the problem. If it is then it's probably not worth the trouble. I have downloaded AccessDatabaseEngine but its 32bit so I don't know? Probably make my life easier if I use SQL Server instead of Access.

I think this question has been asked too many times.

Comment: Are you copying the database to your data directory each time you run your program?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn - Shouldn't the two functions do that or is it I don't understand?

Comment: No the function should not and do not do that. It sounds to me from your description that you have Visual Studio setup to copy your database to your data directory each time you run your program. So it appears that the data is disappearing when in reality it just a new fresh copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, make sure your database is NOT included with your project builds.

In Solution Explorer, find your database and specify **Build Action = None** and **Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy**

[image: screenshot]

Your database should reside in a folder other than your `bin` folder, otherwise every time you fire up your project, you will copy to your output folder the same database that is in your project.

Instead, locate the database somewhere else (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files` or some other location) and connect to it.

There could be other issues with your project, but this is a big one that is jumping out at me.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to and apologies for inconvenience.

Comment: Glad to help. I think you got the downvotes because people didn't understand what you were asking. Got to love people, right?

Comment: This is embarrassing. I was using wrong connection string. I was using Access 2007 when I should have been using Access 2002-2003 version.

Comment: LOL - ah, that's fine. You got it figured out, at least. Still, be sure not to work from a database in your bin folder, or you'll overwrite it with each rebuild.